# REStFul API how to deal with feeedback endpoint

Tags: rest, restful-url, restful-architecture, plural

I'm building a RESTful API amongst others I have the following endpoint:

- /api/feedback

REST resources should use their plural forms. In this case, Feedback is a mass noun, that is it doesn't have a plural form. How should I deal with it?

Should it be /api/feedback or /api/feedbacks?

Comment: "*Feedback*" is an uncountable noun. As such, it has no plural form. So, just use `/api/feedback`.

Comment: if this is a POST service you can just use `api/feedback`. Its meaning will be "POST one feedback". The singular/plural problem would happen only for GET services, where you'd have to distinguish between "GET all feedbacks" and "GET one feedback". In this case, you would typically  have `api/feedbacks` for the former and `api/feedbacks/{id}` for the latter.

Comment: Thanks guys. I like @FrancescoForesti 's suggestion. That helps to resolve GET request for one and many requests.